# Increase memory to memcached

Tags: linux, redhat, memory, cache, memcached

I need to increase the memory size for memcached. I have done this before, but I cannot remember all the steps that I took. If I remember correctly, I downloaded /etc/sysconfig/memcached and changed `CACHESIZE=64` to `CACHESIZE=1024`. However I am not sure if that is how it is supposed to be done.

Anyone that could guide me into how I do this? Also a command that confirms the change would be useful. I am running RedHat x86_64 es5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the memcached rpms, yes, editing the CACHESIZE in /etc/sysconfig/memcached is the correct way to do it.

You'll need to restart memcached if it's already running.

To check that it's changed, do a "ps aux | grep memcached" and look at the memcached arguments for the -m flag.  If it matches what you put in the /etc/sysconfig/memcached CACHESIZE variable, you should be good.